# undefined control sequence <argument> \textminus in listing

Tags: listings, python, undefined

I tried to insert python code in my LaTeX document for a project of mine. For this, I used the *listings* package. For some reason unknown to me, a minus sign in my python code throws an

> !undefined control sequence
>
> argument \textminus
>
> l.158 for i in range(len(res)-1):
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
>
> of your error message was never \def'ed.

I have been able to reproduce the error using the simple code (not showing my entire code as it's quite long, but kept the same parameters for listings):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\definecolor{codeorange}{rgb}{1,0.5,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codeyellow}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0}

\lstdefinestyle{pythonsub}{
    commentstyle = \color{codegray},
    keywordstyle = \color{codeorange},
    stringstyle = \color{codeyellow},
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false, 
    tabsize = 4,
}

\parindent 0ex
\lstset{style=pythonsub}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
 one = 2-1
\end{lstlisting}
```

simply removing the minus sign in my python code (see below) resolves the issue, but of course then it's not the same code.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
 one = 21
\end{lstlisting}
```

other similar characters (+, =, /,...) don't cause any problem. What's the best way to resolve this error?

In case it matters, I'm using TeX maker with MikTeX  2.9.6930 64-bit installed.

Comment: Apart from the fact that your example is missing \begin{document} it compiles fine for me. You probably have an older latex which doesn't fit to your newer listings. Either load \usepackage{textcomp} or check for updates in the miktex console in user *and* admin mode.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. fixed it. The lack of \begin{document} is an accident on my part. I tried some other solutions first and therefore had to rewrite my test code in stack exchange. Forgot to add \begin{document} and \end{document}.