# Command \textminus unavailable in encoding OT1

Tags: listings, font-encodings

When I try to compile my document I get the error as in the title. I guess it is related to the Matlab code I submit, but I do not know how to correct this.

```
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{listings}
\newsavebox{\mybox}

\usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{ 
        language=Matlab,                        % choose the language of the code
    %   basicstyle=10pt,                    % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
        numbers=left,                           % where to put the line-numbers
        numberstyle=\footnotesize,              % the size of the fonts that are used for the line-numbers
        stepnumber=1,                               % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1 each line will be numbered
        numbersep=5pt,                          % how far the line-numbers are from the code
    %   backgroundcolor=\color{white},      % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
        showspaces=false,                       % show spaces adding particular underscores
        showstringspaces=false,                 % underline spaces within strings
        showtabs=false,                             % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    %   frame=single,                               % adds a frame around the code
    %   tabsize=2,                              % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    %   captionpos=b,                               % sets the caption-position to bottom
        breaklines=true,                            % sets automatic line breaking
        breakatwhitespace=false,                % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
        escapeinside={\%*}{*)}                  % if you want to add a comment within your code
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\lstinputlisting[language=Matlab,caption={A Matlab code.}]{identify_m.m}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see my comment here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538168/undefined-control-sequence-argument-textminus-in-listing#comment1359656_538168